# Homologically trivial immersion

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Are there any examples when some manifold $N$ maps in other manifold $M$ as codimension 1 submanifold, its fundamental class is zero in the homology of M, but still this map $i\colon N\to M$ induces a non-trivial homomorphism of homology groups. I'm very interested in case when homology is taken with coefficients in some field, but any counter example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit to make what you are asking clear to *all* users of the site, or delete your question.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: his question is perfectly clear.

Comment: "All users" seems like a very high standard.

Comment: @Hoot all users familiar with the subject

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Could you be more specific about the flaws? I don't know much AT beyond a first course and this looks fine to me — the terms are standard and strung together in a way that makes sense. I'm all for better questions (you could say that the OP hasn't shown much effort and I think that could be fair) but this one at least seems clear.

Comment: @Hoot the user is using poor english grammar. I dont know AT. I just know those are not compete sentences, and it therefore cannot be clear.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck You say it should be clear to all users familiar with AT, then you say it's not clear to you but you don't know AT - these seem contradictory to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider an embedding of a torus $N$ inside $M=(\mathbb R^3 \text{with a line removed})$, such that the torus is the boundary of a regular neighborhood of a curve that goes around the line once. Since $M$ is homotopy equivalent to a circle, the induced map on $H_2(N)\to H_2(M)$ is trivial. Yet on the level of $H_1$ we have a nontrivial map $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$.